# Failed to get Uniform distribution from Gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, uniform-distribution

I read in Chapter 6 in [this book](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-the-bugs-book/) that

> $p(K)\propto 1$ is equivalent to $e^{-K}\sim Gamma(0,0)I(0,1)$

where $K$>0 and is uniform distribution, e.g., $K \sim Uniform(0,100)$; $I(a,b)$ is the truncated distribution to represent interval censoring, whose sole effect is to ensure that all values sampled outside the specified interval are rejected.

I tried the WinBUGS code to find if this statement is true:

```
model{
    # use a small number '0.03' instead of '0', or the program will crash
    exp.ngK ~ dgamma(0.03, 0.03)I(0,1)
    K <- -log(exp.ngK)
}
```

I run the iteration for 1,000,000 times. Unfortunately, $K$ is not a uniform distribution (see left panel in Fig.1 below). Why does this happen?

[image: Fig.1]

**Update:**

According to @whuber♦ comment, I tried $Gamma(1,1)I(0,1)$ for `exp.ngK`. However, `K` seems not a uniform distribution in [0,1] (see left panel in Fig.2, it has a peak). Since I have made one million iterations, I guess `K` may be not uniform?

[image: Fig.2]

Comment: Because "Gamma(0,0)" is nonsense, you have to be careful about interpreting it.  Try plotting, say, `curve(ifelse(x < 1, dgamma(x,1,1e-4)*1e4, 0), 0, 1.1, n=501)`: that produces a uniform distribution.  However, that doesn't even seem to be what the quotation says: it claims that the *negative log* of a uniformly distributed variable has a "Gamma(0,0)" distribution.  It doesn't: it has a Gamma(1,1) distribution.

Comment: @whuber I tried gamma(1,1)I(0,1). However, K seems not uniform. See "Update" in my post

Comment: I'm sorry: in my haste I got it backwards.  When you exponentiate an exponential variate you get a uniform.   E.g., the `R` command `hist(exp(-rexp(1e6)))` will display a histogram of a million realizations and this histogram will be clearly uniform.  It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish, though, since there are much easier ways to generate uniform random numbers!